# Pandas - Apply logic to every column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe that has 50 columns. I am trying to apply a certain logic to every column

Logic I am trying to apply is

```
df[1] = df[1].str.split("'",expand=True)
```

The above logic works well for column with `index 1`, how could I extend this to every column in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is neater to use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def custom_split(string):
    return string.str.split("'", expand=True)

df.apply(custom_split)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Just did

```
for column in sprint_df:
    sprint_df[column] = sprint_df[column].str.split("'",expand=True)
```

That worked.